AWS Athena S3 log permission denied on root account
I have a S3 bucket mybucketlogs which was created via the S3 logging functionality from another bucket. My root account is the owner of both buckets and all objects within both buckets.
I followed the guide from here https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena replacing the path with the root of my bucket where the logs are stored e.g. s3:/mybucketlog/ I'm able to create the table and external database however when I go to run a query SELECT * FROM "s3_access_logs_db"."mybucket_logs" limit 10;
I get an access denied error:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: -; S3 Extended Request ID: ; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID:  (Bucket: mybucketlogs, Key: 2024/01/02/)
This query ran against the "s3_access_logs_db" database, unless qualified by the query.

I'm running this on the root account so I'm not sure why there is a permission error, I can access the S3 bucket directly from the console and download any file.
I tried adding S3 Bucket policy to the bucket as below, but that didn't work as well
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3-Console-Auto-Gen-Policy-XXXXXXXXXX",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "athena.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my root id>:root"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Create Table query is as follows:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_access_logs_db.mybucket_logs(
 `bucketowner` STRING, 
 `bucket_name` STRING, 
 `requestdatetime` STRING, 
 `remoteip` STRING, 
 `requester` STRING, 
 `requestid` STRING, 
 `operation` STRING, 
 `key` STRING, 
 `request_uri` STRING, 
 `httpstatus` STRING, 
 `errorcode` STRING, 
 `bytessent` BIGINT, 
 `objectsize` BIGINT, 
 `totaltime` STRING, 
 `turnaroundtime` STRING, 
 `referrer` STRING, 
 `useragent` STRING, 
 `versionid` STRING, 
 `hostid` STRING, 
 `sigv` STRING, 
 `ciphersuite` STRING, 
 `authtype` STRING, 
 `endpoint` STRING, 
 `tlsversion` STRING,
 `accesspointarn` STRING,
 `aclrequired` STRING)
 PARTITIONED BY (
   `timestamp` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
 'input.regex'='([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \\[(.*?)\\] ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\"[^\"]*\"|-) (-|[0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\"[^\"]*\"|-) ([^ ]*)(?: ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*))?.*$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
 's3://mybucketlogs/'
 TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.timestamp.format'='yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.timestamp.interval'='1', 
  'projection.timestamp.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
  'projection.timestamp.range'='2024/01/01,NOW', 
  'projection.timestamp.type'='date', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://mybucketlogs/${timestamp}')

The S3 Bucket policy for the mybucketlogs, I tried adding direct Athena and full permissions for my root ARN even thou I shouldn't need that but that did not work.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3-Console-Auto-Gen-Policy-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "athena.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs "
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketlogs "
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Can you share your CREATE TABLE query?

@jellycsc added! Maybe I did something wrong there not sure

Can you share the bucket policy of both source and destination buckets?

@Aravindanvaithialingam added the source ARN, I have no permissions set on the destination ARN but that doesn't seem to be the issue as it can't read from the bucket. It is writing to the destination bucket with no permissions as well.

Sorry I don't get it, you work on root account and have no permissions to set on destin ARN? and what do you mean by, "it can't read from the bucket, but has PutObject permission as it's writing to the destin bucket without permissions". Could you describe a bit more in details.

@pyCthon are there any SCPs on your account that are being applied? Is your aws account a member of an organization and did your admin apply any policies to it?

No I'm the full owner of the account @HSchmale unless somehow the AWS activate program is blocking it on me?

Are there any further details in your cloud trail logs on what might be going on?

I'll enable that and try again @HSchmale

There are some spaces in the policy that you have shared.
Specifically around the resource ARNs.
Is the shared policy matching the policy that you are using?

@razboy just a typo, fixed above, it won't save with the space.
